# AWS SOC 2 API Gateway / CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, standards-compliance, soc

Traditionally AWS components, EC2, etc., are SOC 2 certified and organization leverage this via the carve out method for do a SOC 2 for their entire application.  As the API Gateway or CloudFront is not certified or scheduled, is it still possible to become certified in using those functions?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for letting us know your interest in using API Gateway for a SOC 2 compliant application.  Large enterprise firms require SOC 2 compliance throughout all the SaaS providers they work with, and these SaaS providers also need to use SOC 2 compliant vendors.  I have seen a few requests for this in the past and we are evaluating SOC 2 compliance, however, I do not have an ETA at this time.